# How can I use Regex to pull just the CN from a Distinguished Name with PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, ldap

I have a bunch of strings that are DN's of groups from AD. I need to pull out the Common Name.
An example string is "CN=Group Name I Want,OU=Group Container,DC=corp,DC=test,DC=local"

What I am looking for is some PowerShell Code that will pull "Group Name I Want" out of that string and discard the rest.

I can rip of the CN with this

```
$s = "CN=Group Name I Want,OU=Group Container,DC=corp,DC=test,DC=local"
$s = $s.Remove(0,3)
```

But after that, I don't have a good way to rip off everthing starting at ",OU"

I am sure there is some regex that will do this but I need some help figuring it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$s = "CN=Group Name I Want,OU=Group Container,DC=corp,DC=test,DC=local"
$s -replace "(CN=)(.*?),.*",'$2'
```

Comment: much cleaner than -split method

Comment: You should account for a CN that has a comma in the name - e.g. "CN=Surname\, First,OU=Group,DC=corp" - something like '(CN=)(.*?)(?<!\\),.*','$2' would do the correct negative lookbehind to filter out commas with a leading slash.

Comment: I am not sure I can agree with this methodology. LDAP data is not strings, DNs in particular are of `distinguishedName` syntax. Language substitutions, comparisons, and ordering operators should not, in general, be used with data retrieved from a directory server, unless those operators support the use of ordering and matching rules, in this case to figure out substitutions.

Comment: for the php folks out there that's: preg_replace('/(CN=)(.*?),.*/','$2',$dn);

Answer (score 2):

An even shorter variation on [jon Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021945/jon-z)'s answer:

```
$s = "CN=Group Name I Want,OU=Group Container,DC=corp,DC=test,DC=local"
$s = $s -replace '^CN=|,.*$'
```

The `^` and `$` are the string beginning and end anchors. The `|` is an "or".

The matches are the `CN=` at the beginning of the line *or* a string that starts with a comma and goes to the end of the line (i.e. everything after the CN). The `replace` is replacing with nothing, so you're discarding all the matches and leaving just the CN itself.

That obviously does **not** work if you have a comma in your CN (ugh).

Assuming such a comma is followed by a space, this will work and be fine for the previous examples (`\S` - non whitespace char):

```
$s = $s -replace '^CN=|,\S.*$'
```

I tested to see if [jon Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021945/jon-z)'s or this variation was faster to execute. With 1,470,000 DNs, the first took 36.87s to execute and the one here took 34.75. Not really a lot in it.

That was reading the DNs out of a file. Bizarrely, "slurping" the file into an array and executing over that took both regexes a minute longer. The PC was not memory-bound - the file was only 100MB. Can't be bothered getting to the bottom of that one right now!

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "CN=Group Name I Want,OU=Group Container,DC=corp,DC=test,DC=local"
$s1 = ($s -split ",*..=")[1]
$s1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "CN=Hall\, Jeremy,OU=Group Container,DC=corp,DC=test,DC=local"
$s1 = ($s -split ",*..=")[1]
$s1
```

This works for me - however, I have a \, left in name output.  (I'm pulling the manager property from the get-aduser function and it prints the distinguishedName.  Hall\, Jeremy is one example of what I'm left with.

Anyone want to take a stab?

Answer (score 0):

Using the various answers in this thread, I came up with the following:

$s = ($s -split ",*..=")[1]

$s = $s.Remove($s.IndexOf("\"),1)

$s

Answer (score 0):

```
$DN = Get-ADUser Username -Properties * | Select DistinguishedName | ForEach-Object {($_.DistinguishedName) -replace('\\','')}
$OUTemp = $DN -creplace "^[^,]*,",""
$OU = $OUTemp -creplace "^[^,]*,",""
$OU
```

This worked for me after lots of searching. I am not proud of the redundancy in lines 2 and 3 but I don't know how to make it work on a single line.

The "-replace" at the end of the first line took care of DistinguishedNames that were formatted as CN=LastName\, FirstName when the \ escape character was present. It doesn't negatviely affect at name without out it.

The results of my $OU is OU=ChildOU2,OU=ChildOU1,OU=ParentOU,DC=DOMAIN,DC=local