# Parsing and removing text with cmd or powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I've checked quite a few other questions here but was unable to find what I need. I am currently trying to automate the process of finding out what VMs are in what Hyper V servers. Here is my current script.

```
@echo off
set /P dc= "Which DC do you want? " 
dsquery computer -name %DC%VUT* > dsquery.txt
type dsquery.txt | findstr /v IMAGINGOU | findstr /v OTHEROU > dsquery2.txt
powershell -command Get-Content dsquery2.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"CN=', "" } | Set-Content dsquery3.txt
powershell -command Get-Content dsquery3.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ',OU=CAM,OU=Exchange,OU=Server,DC=RED001,DC=local"', "" } | Set-Content serverlist.txt
powershell -command .\Get-HyperVMod.ps1 -file output.csv
```

The problem I have hit is the servers that I can do dsquery from (Win2k3) can't do the ForEach-Object because they have an older version of Powershell and the Win2k8 servers that can do the ForEach-Object can't do a dsquery.

Here is a sample of the dsquery output that I am trying to parse and remove all but the server name.

```
"CN=SERVER001,OU=VUT,OU=Infastructure,OU=Server,DC=dcname,DC=local"
"CN=SERVER008,OU=ImagingWDS,DC=red002,DC=local"
```

Output should be

```
SERVER001
SERVER008
```

Any suggestions on either doing this with another method or just my small problem of removing the extra text from the file.

Answer (score 1):

run this against your dsquery.txt, it will parse what you need.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::Echos your Computer Name only.
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==," %%G IN (dsquery.txt) DO echo %%H
pause
endlocal
```

basically what it does is uses two different delimeters: "=" and "," which immediately surround your server names. and looks only for that second token. It works based on the strings you provided above.

Answer (score 0):

The `ForEach-Object` cmdlet was introduced in PowerShell V1 so you'll have it there.

Jon's regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729566/how-can-i-use-regex-to-pull-just-the-cn-from-a-distinguished-name-with-powershel) shows you how you can pull the common name from a LDAP string.

This will apply the regex to each line in a text file and return the result.

```
Get-Content file.txt | % { $_ -replace '(CN=)(.*?),.*', '$2' }
```

**Update** 
Here's how your batch script would translate into PowerShell:

```
$dc = Read-Host "Which DC do you want?"
& dsquery computer -name "${dc}VUT*" | % { 
    # Do your processing here...
    $_ -replace '(CN=)(.*?),.*', '$2' 
}
```

Comment: That works but only if I enclose it in quotes which leaves the output with quotes. I assume it have to do because I am calling a powershell command from a batch file 

`powershell -command "Get-Content dsquery2.txt | % { $_ -replace '(CN=)(.*?),.*', '$2' }"`

Comment: @Edwin Why don't you just go all PowerShell instead of mixing the two? Life would be much easier :-)

Comment: I honestly don't know anything about powershell. Just trying to do the best I can as quickly as I can with what I know. I'll try and make the whole thing in Powershell then since I can't seem to get it to work with the two.

Comment: @Edwin I updated my answer to show you how you can translate your batch script into a pure PowerShell script. If you show me what your original text file looks like and describe the result you want I can add an example to do that.