# Powershell Email format and retrieving CN from Certificate subject

Tags: email, powershell, notifications, certificate

I'm trying to create a powershell script that will alert me when one or more of my certificates are about to expire.I combined some scripts i found on internet and it seems to work fine. The only problem is when sending the email im getting just one big row with all certificate one behind the other. I'd preffer to get more of a list like:
Certificate 1
Subject: CN =hello
Expiration:2/11/2017 1:00:00 AM

Certificate 2
Subject: CN =hello2
Expiration:2/11/2017 1:00:00 AM

If possible i would also like some help on how to just get the CN from the certificate subject rather the the complete subject with (OU, O, L, S,C)

Here is my current script:

```
import-module webadministration
$DaysToExpiration = 700 #just modify this date for more or less

$expirationDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($DaysToExpiration)


$body = Get-ChildItem CERT:LocalMachine/My | 
Where {$_.NotAfter -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays($DaysToExpiration)}

$body | select  Subject, @{Name="Expiration"; Expression = {$_.NotAfter}} | fl | out-string

$emailSmtpServer = "172.17.1.236"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "25"
$emailSmtpUser = "test"
$emailSmtpPass = "test"

$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

$PCName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$emailMessage.From  = "$PCName@test.com"
$emailMessage.To.Add( "test@dev.test.de" )
$emailMessage.Body  = $body | select Subject, @{Name="Expiration"; Expression = {$_.NotAfter}} | fl | out-string
$emailMessage.Subject = "Certificates Expiring within $DaysToExpiration days"
$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , $emailSmtpServerPort )
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass );



if ($emailMessage.Body.Length -gt 1)
{
  Write-host "Sending Email"
  $SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for the same and I found the following stack overflow 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729566/how-can-i-use-regex-to-pull-just-the-cn-from-a-distinguished-name-with-powershel)

```
$s = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\localmachine\My'| select subject
$s -replace "(CN=)(.*?),.*",'$2'
$s = $s -replace "@{Subject="
```

OR the non regex way ..

```
$sub = $_.Subject.split(",")[0].split("=")
$sub[1] = $sub[1] -replace "\*","star" 
$sub[1]
```

It is working for most domain certificates but and I can see some issues with self certificates and server certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Either configure $emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $false or create an HTML body.