# Regex date parsing

Tags: regex, powershell

Can someone help me with a regex to pull

`Wed Oct 31` from the below

```
Date:   Wed Oct 31 12:55:00 2018 -0500
```

Obviously the date will change day to day in the log.

Comment: Have to ask: is this a situation where you must parse date-time output?

Comment: In case your local time zone is not `-0500` you might hit a different day without using `[datetime]::parseexact()` and a matching pattern.

Comment: <p>I have a file that contains information from a GIT log.<br>
Date:   Wed Oct 31 12:55:00 2018 -0500<br>
id:202847 Merge branch ‘release/2.6.0’ into release/3.0.0 # Conflicts:</p>
<h1><a id="configurationgsrcgwjobPolicyChangeProcessgs_3"></a>configuration/gsrc/gw/job/PolicyChangeProcess.gs</h1>
<p>I just need to pull whatever date is in the log day to day and put it into a variable so I can add it to the body of an email. I’m just having trouble with the REGEX to pull dates that are DAY MONTH #DATE (Tue Nov 6).</p>

Comment: sorry - new to markdown and i still dont have the hang of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've asked for a regular expression but your example already shows a pitfall in the form of a timezone!

Just using a regular expression alone might get you the wrong day when the timezone offset pushes it across midnight. I'd recommend instead using `[DateTime]::TryParseExact` instead and then using a Date string format to get it into the form you need:

```
$Line = "Date:   Wed Oct 31 12:55:00 2018 -0500"

[DateTime] $Date = New-Object DateTime

$Success = [DateTime]::TryParseExact($Line,
    "'Date:   'ddd MMM dd HH':'mm':'ss yyyy zzz",
    [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
    [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,
    [ref] $Date)

if ($Success) {
    $Date.ToString("ddd MMM dd")
}
```

The above example prints out

```
Wed Oct 31
```

Answer (score 2):

this aint a regex, but it seems to do the job ... [*grin*]

```
$FullDateString = 'Date: Wed Oct 31 12:55:00 2018 -0500'
# the `.Split()` version doesn't take into account random extra spaces in the source
#    use the next line instead
#$DateString = $FullDateString.Split(' ')[1..3] -join ' '
$DateString = ($FullDateString -split '\s+')[1..3] -join ' '

$DateString
```

output = `Wed Oct 31`

what happened above ...

- split on the spaces
- took the 2nd thru 4th [1..3] items from the resulting array
- joined them with a "space" delimiter

---

you may want to use a more flexible method and 1st convert to a `[datetime]` object and then use `.ToString()` with your preferred format.

Answer (score 1):

Give a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/previous-versions/technet-magazine/cc137764(v=msdn.10)) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729566/how-can-i-use-regex-to-pull-just-the-cn-from-a-distinguished-name-with-powershel). With that, you can find a pretty easy regex to solve your problem!

Here's what I have:

```
$date = 'Date: Wed Oct 31 12:55:00 2018 -0500'
$date -replace "Date: (\w{3} \w{3} \d{2}) .*", '$1'
```

I don't know what you really want to do, so just change the regex as you want ;)