# powershell Extract part of output

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Good day,

I have a script that I wrote that gathers computer information from AD. 
One specific property I am gathering is the MemberOf.  When I run the script it outputs the full path for the group that computer account is a member of. I want just the group name. Please see below:

```
get-qadcomputer -identity $computer | format-list -property Name, AccountIsDisabled, whenCreated, whenChanged, Description, AllMemberOf, ParentContainerDN
```

My output looks like:

```
Name              : SALESWS3381FPO
AccountIsDisabled : False
whenCreated       : 3/7/2018 9:44:07 AM
whenChanged       : 12/24/2018 4:18:04 AM
Description       : BLDG 589 FLR 2 RM 567
AllMemberOf       : {CN=SALES-ADOBEPRO-Win10_COMPUTERS,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Site Specific
                    OUs,OU=sales,DC=example,DC=com}
ParentContainerDN : OU=Bldg 589,OU=Desktops,OU=sales,DC=example,DC=com
```

So, for AllMemberOf, I want it to say   **AllMemberOf: SALES-ADOBEPRO-Win10_Computers**

We are running Active Roles Client on our machines.

Comment: the `-Identity` parameter of `Get-ADGroup` accepts a DN, so you can use that to look up the proper name via the `.Name` property.

Comment: We can't use Get-ADGroup. On our systems we are using Active Roles Console

Comment: ah! well, then, if your DN is very consistent you can use a simple regex like this ...`$VarName.Split('=')[1].Split(',')[0]`. that works with your sample DN to give `SALES-ADOBEPRO-Win10_COMPUTERS`.

Comment: Thank you Lee for your reply. I am not familiar with regex and couldn't figure out how to implement your solution.

Comment: that is not regex. [*grin*] you use the code above by applying the stuff after the `$VarName` to any string. it looks like your `.AllMemberOf` property is a collection of some sort - likely an array - that holds only one item. so you would use `.AllmemberOf[0].Split('=')[1].Split(',')[0]` to get the the CN part of the sample you show.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thank you for explaining that.  I will be noting that for future reference.  New to PowerShell, but I am so impressed with how powerfull it is.  Thank you again!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to kinda-sorts help ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the a simple regular expression to get the value of the group from the complete string.

By using a calculated property to your format-list, you can extract and keep only the group name.

`@{n='AllMemberOf ';e={$_.AllMemberOf -replace "(CN=)(.*?),.*",'$2'}}`

**Here's your modified code sample applying that calculated property:**

```
get-qadcomputer -identity $computer | format-list -property Name, AccountIsDisabled, whenCreated, whenChanged, Description, @{n='AllMemberOf ';e={$_.AllMemberOf -replace "(CN=)(.*?),.*",'$2'}}, ParentContainerDN
```

References :

[4sysops - Add a calculated property with Select-Object in Powershell](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/)

[StackOverflow — How can I use Regex to pull just the CN from a Distinguished Name with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8729599/934946)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I am new to powershell and was not aware of the calculated property.  Thank you very much!